# Error running jekyll locally (rvm gemset issue)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, jekyll

I installed ruby 1.9.3 thru RVM, and now want to get the rekyll gem so that I can test my blog locally. When I `gem install jekyll` it intalls ok, but when i try to run `jekyll --server` i get an error:

```
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find jekyll (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/jekyll:18:in `<main>'
```

I Can see it in the list when I `gem list` - any ideas what is wrong?

I also tried `RVMSUDO gem install jekyll` to no avail.

If it's any use at all, my rvm info:

```
system:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin Matts-MacBook-Air.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.13.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "8 days 23 hours 59 minutes 32 seconds ago"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/matt/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Well, your GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH vars should be set, but they're not in your 'rvm info' output. Did you complete the rvm install (not installing ruby--the install of rvm itself) by adding stuff to your .bashrc and sourcing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rvm use 1.9.3@test --create` - Use & created gemset.

`gem install jekyll` - Install the gem.

The most important step was to use ruby `rvm use 1.9.3`. RVM by default should use and set default first installed ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get back to basics of using RVM:

- rvm screencast http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm
- rvm cheatsheet http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/

It should be only few minutes to check them - and they should allow you to avoid further confusions.

Comment: Thanks - I admit I am a total RVM n00b.