# Bundle Install Fails

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I am getting an error while running bundle install in my rails project.

```
sahil@debian:~/workspace/blog$ bundle install
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

Ruby

```
sahil@debian:~/workspace/blog$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86__64-linux]

sahil@debian:~/workspace/blog$ which ruby
/home/sahil/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

Received the below error while installing ruby through rvm.

```
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /home/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby -d /home/sahil/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.3/setup.rb --verbose',
please read /home/sahil/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
```

rvm env

```
sahil@debian:~$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
 - /home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
 - /home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => t
```

rvm env looks ok. Not sure what have I missed.

Comment: did you "sudo gem install bundler"? Then you circumvented rvm

Comment: I did "gem install bundler" after installing rvm and ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow this basics steps for using RVM (copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15570121/497756):

```
rvm install 2.0.0
rvm use 2.0.0 --default # The default arg is needed only first time
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

also another answer showing more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591301/497756